# Too many for X in Y

Tags: python, list

is there a better way to do this...? I feel that so many For can't be good.

Note that ListaOnline is merely a list of usernames, and those usernames usually have [] characters in their nicknames. I hope that it's not confusing.

```
ListaOnline = ['[YOLO]someone', 'Another person', 'example']
ListaJugadores = [['[YOLO]someone', ['healer', 'tank']], ['example', ['healer', 'dps']]]
ListaMeta = Lista Meta: ['healer', 'tank', 'dps', 'dps', 'dps', 'support', 'support']
ListaResultado = [['healer', []], ['tank', []], ['dps', []], ['dps', []], ['dps', []], ['support', []], ['support', []]]
for i in ListaOnline: #for each player online
    for j in ListaJugadores: #check players in database
        if j[0] == i: #and if found
            for k in ListaMeta: #for each role in the Meta
                for l in j[1]: #for each item in player's roles
                    if k in l: #if the player has this role
                        for m in ListaResultado: #for each role in ListaResultado
                            if k in m: #if the role matches
                                m[1].append(i) #add player to the list
print(str(ListaResultado))

>>> [['healer', ['[YOLO]someone', 'example']], ['tank', ['[YOLO]someone']], ['dps', ['example']], ['dps', []], ['dps', []], ['support', []], ['support', []]]
```

The expected output is to get a list with each player added to the roles they are saved in the database. The ListaOnline, ListaJugadores and ListaMeta lists would be changing every day so each time this code runs would need to check the new roles availibles and fill the ListaResultado according to the expected roles in the Meta.

Comment: It looks like you should be using dictionaries instead of lists of lists with the key as the first element of the list.

Comment: From the look of it your code is supposed to be run as cron job or something similar, Am I understanding your requirement properly?

Comment: It's suppose to be added as a command for a TeamSpeak bot. Players can use a command to save their roles in the database. The admin can use another command to save different Meta lists. The admin can use another command that creates a list of all users online that can fit in a role (this code) and then the bot should tell them which role to use to make the most optimal composition, but that part is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could simplify your code.

```
ListaOnline = ['[YOLO]someone', 'Another person', 'example']
DictJugadores = {'[YOLO]someone': ['healer', 'tank'], 'example': ['healer', 'dps'] }
ListaMeta = ['healer', 'tank', 'dps', 'dps', 'dps', 'support', 'support']
DictResultado = dict((role, []) for role in ListaMeta)
for user in ListaOnline: #for each player online
    if user in DictJugadores:
        for role in DictJugadores[user]:
            DictResultado[role].append(user)
print(str(DictResultado))
```

Will give you:

```
{'healer': ['[YOLO]someone', 'example'], 'support': [], 'tank' : ['[YOLO]someone'], 'dps': ['example']}
```

And if you don't know how to convert the lists to dicts:

```
def convert_list_to_dict(list_with_keys):
    d = {}
    for l in list_with_keys:
        d[l[0]] = l[1]
    return d
```

And in the opposite direction:

```
def convert_dict_to_list(my_dict):
    l = []
    for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
        l.append([k,v])
    return l
```

You can also abuse python nice list and dicts syntax sugar to get the job done in one line:

```
DictResultado = dict( (r, [u for u in ListaOnline 
                            if u in DictJugadores and r in DictJugadores[u]]) 
                      for r in ListaMeta )
```

(This is also abusing python lazy evaluation of *and* expression to avoid a KeyError in the dictionary. That is, the order in `if u in DictJugadores and r in DictJugadores[u]` really matters).

But I would go with the for loop solution, since it is clearer and easier to grasp in one look. As *Writing Solid Code* book recommends, you should do clean and boring code and try to not abuse language's particular syntax.

By the way, I highly recommend you to try to follow pep 8 in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListaJugadores = [['[YOLO]someone', ['healer', 'tank']], ['example', ['healer', 'dps']]]
```

Can be better represented by:

```
ListaJugadores = {'[YOLO]someone': ['healer', 'tank'], 'example': ['healer', 'dps']}
```

This way is useful: now you can do lookups:

```
> ListaJugadores['[YOLO]someone]
> ['healer', 'tank']
```

This is a dictionary, and this can eventually be expanded. Maybe you want to include a little more info:

```
ListaJugadores = {'[YOLO]someone': {'roles': ['healer', 'tank'], 'last_login': '01-01-1990'}}
```

The runtime for lookups is also O(1) which is... really nice. :)

This doesn't get you the entire way there. If you want to build your `ListaResultado` object, you'd still have to do something like..

```
ListaResultado = {'healer': [], 'tank': [], 'dps': []}

for user in ListaOnline:
    if user in DictJugadores:
        for role in DictJugadores[user]:
            ListaResultado[role].append(user)
```

However, eventually it might be best to move this to a relational database. Then you can just query all online users and get their roles! It'd be very easy, and it moves your data model into a safe place.

Also, since you're learning: look into PEP8 style guides. Python convention is to use under_score variable names :)

Comment: If you look at something like sqlalchemy you can avoid getting into all the SQL internals and make your code DB agnostic.

Comment: Yup, ORMs are a good place to start! PeeWee is a very lightweight and easy-to-learn one.